# How to include two libraries of different versions in Android

Tags: android, dependency-management

For the sence of backward compatibility I need to include two versions of the same barcode reading lib in my App.

For barcodes of old format I will use the old lib. 
For barcodes of new format I will use the new lib.

**Problem**:
The classes in both libs have the same names.

**Question**:
What is the best way to include both libs in my App without a name clash?

**What I tried:** 
I tried to create two lib-projects - one for each lib. I tried to forbid direct access to the libs by using Build Path Access Rules - but the App still sees both libs.

Comment: why is your library not backward compatible with the old barcode format?

Comment: Please take the circumstances as given

Comment: shout at the author of the library hard enough so they will make a compatible version, then. More seriously, do you have the source, or is it a binary distribution?

Answer (score 3):

I assume you do not have the source code for this lib, correct?

### Having source code:

You should build one library that supports both, old and new format.

### Having libs but no source:

This is only possible if you use a custom `ClassLoader`. Check [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Although extreme, you have the option of changing the root of the namespace of the old library.

Just make sure you do it with refactoring so that the internal library classes change accordingly.